Replacement of setProperties() and getProperties() methods from CMSObject
In my extension i have some classes which extends CMSObject, in these classes there are some usages of setProperties() and getProperties() methods. With the future of removing of CMSObject class from Joomla! 6.0 i'am looking to replace the methods.
How can-i use Registry class to replace setProperties() and getProperties() methods ?
